# Two different IP addresses points to same azure deployment

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution with several projects inside. Four projects are Windows azure roles.

ProjectA [WorkerRole]
ProjectB [WorkerRole]
ProjectC [WebRole]
ProjectD [WebRole]

With F5 all four projects will start. In the Emulator I can see the different IP Addresses for ProjectC and ProjectD. In the Console Output I can see that ProjectC is really ProjectC and ProjectD is really ProjectD. But if I call the applications with the browser, I always get ProjectC. With both IP Addresses.

Any succestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the azure toolkit and the azure emulator. This solved my problem.